# jquery hiding image on page load depending on title

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide an image on page load, **depending on its title**
This does not seem to work.. when i put this in my code, i get an alert for all the images that have a title (which is correct):

```
$('article a.tooltip img').load(function(){
    if(this.title != ""){
        alert(this.title);
 }

});
```

In my CSS file I disabled the display of all images at first:

```
.contact a.tooltip{
    display: none;
}
```

now i want to **show** all the images with non empty title, which doesnt work:

```
$('article a.tooltip img').load(function(){
    if(this.title != ""){
        this.show();
        alert(this.title);
 }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

article a.tooltip img is not hidden.
.contact a.tooltip is hidden.

Change

```
$('article a.tooltip img').load(function(){
    if(this.title != ""){
        this.show();
        alert(this.title);
 }

});
```

to

```
$('article a.tooltip img').load(function(){
    if(this.title != ""){
        this.parent().show();
        alert(this.title);
 }

});
```

Comment: hey man it will work only on first image so, use each function instead!

Comment: seems logical, but when i change to:

CSS:

 .contact a.tooltip img{
 display: none;
}

and 

        $('.contact a.tooltip img').load(function(){
            if(this.title != ""){
                this.show();
                alert(this.title);
         }

        });

i get same result.. nothing is shown
without the this.show, i get correct alerts again on non-empty titles

Comment: First of all, `this` is a native DOM element, it has no `parent()` or `show()` method, as that is only for jQuery objects. Secondly, this does'nt iterate, so it only works for the first image. And third, you don't need to wait for the images to load at all, as the title is available as soon as the image is added to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.
Taking $(this) instead of this did it!

Comment: @MathiasColpaert - Good for you, accepting an answer that does'nt work and all! That's useful for posterity?

Comment: @adeneo well I requested for a post edit, if not I will repost correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$("article a.tooltip img").each( function() {
var t = $(this).attr("title");
if(t!=// some title) {
$(this).parent("a.tooltip").show();
}
else {
$(this).parent("a.tooltip").remove();
}
```

Comment: as you have `display:none` every image so, it will check each image title and depending upon it, it will show that images that you want!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$(this)` and `.attr()` like this:

```
$('article a.tooltip img').load(function(){
  if($(this).attr('title') != ""){
    $(this).show();
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
  }
});
```

hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

article a.tooltip img is not hidden. .contact a.tooltip is hidden.

Change

```
$('article a.tooltip img').load(function(){
    if(this.title != ""){
        this.show();
        alert(this.title);
 }

});
```

to

```
$('article a.tooltip img').load(function(){
    if(this.title != ""){
        $(this).parent().show();
        alert(this.title);
 }

});
```